# Can't resolve 'node:http

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-https

I am doing reactjs project when I tried to run npm start
./node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'node:http' in 'C:\Users\Aorat\OneDrive\Desktop\Fam-Jam-Family-Application\client\node_modules\node-fetch\src'

Comment: How did you initialize the project? Did you create your index.js file and run npm init or did you run something like create-react-app? If you used create-react-app, did you try re-initializing the project in a different location?

Comment: I did all of that

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and after trying a few things to no avail I got around it by installing node-fetch v2 rather than using the latest, v3.